# How to count number of instances in AWS PHP SDK2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, composer-php

Assume composer is installed and you need to setup an ec2 client.

Comment: Why are you posting a question and answering it yourself?

Comment: @relentless "To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged." [stackoverflow.com](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose SDK setup with recommended method using Composer. First call `aws_setup`then create an ec2 client object with security credentials. Since composer has been invoked, it will automatically load required libraries.

Then use DescribeInstances to get all running instances.

I packaged the function countInstances so it can be reused. You can call DescribeInstances with
with an array to filter results which is posted at the end.

Setup as follows:

```
require('/PATH/TO/MY/COMPOSER/vendor/autoload.php');

function aws_setup()
{
    $conf_aws = array();
    $conf_aws['key'] = 'MYKEY';
    $conf_aws['secret'] = 'MYSECRET';
    $conf_aws['region'] = 'us-east-1';
    return $conf_aws;
}

function countInstances($list)
{
  $count = 0;
  foreach($list['Reservations'] as $instances)
  {
    foreach($instances['Instances'] as $instance)
    {
      $count++;
    }
  }
  return $count;
}

$config = aws_setup();

$ec2Client = \Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client::factory($config);

$list = $ec2Client->DescribeInstances();

echo "Number of running instances: " . countInstances($list);
```

If you want to filter your results try something like this as a parameter to DescribeInstances:

```
array('Filters' => array(array('Name' => 'tag-value', 'Values' => array('MY_INSTANCE_TAG'))));
```

The code executes without error, but I had to adapt it to post it here.

EDIT: Added list of instances to countInstances function. Otherwise it wouldn't be visible.